# Loosing the generic type parameter when calling getActualTypeArguments

Tags: java, generics

```
public class RemoveCategoryCommandHandler extends BaseCommandHandler<Categenter code hereory>
    implements CommandHandler<RemoveCategory> {

        public RemoveCategoryCommandHandler(RepositoryFactory repositoryfactory) {
        super(repositoryfactory);
        }


        public abstract class BaseCommandHandler<T extends AggregateRoot> {

            protected final Repository<T> repository;

            protected BaseCommandHandler(RepositoryFactory repositoryfactory) {
                this.repository = repositoryfactory.<T>create();
            }

        }


        public class RepositoryFactory {
            private final EventStore eventstore;
            private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;

            public RepositoryFactory(EventStore eventstore, EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
                this.eventstore = eventstore;
                this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
            }
            public <T extends AggregateRoot> Repository<T> create() {

                return new AggregateRepository<T>(eventstore, eventPublisher) {
                    @Override
                    public void save(T aggregate, int version) {
                        super.save(aggregate, version);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

> Given the above scenario where in RemoveCategoryCommandHandler I am
>   passing a RepositoryFactory which return me an AgreegateRepository of
>   Type T.
>
> **When I am calling the below code , `clazz = getclass()` on repository.**

```
 ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              Class<? extends AggregateRoot> parameterizedClazz = (Class<? extends AggregateRoot>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

repository = new AggregateRepository<Category>(store, new SimpleEventPublisher(resolver)) {
    @Override
    public void save(Category aggregate, int version) {
        super.save(aggregate, version);
    }
};
```

> I am getting the below error
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast
>   to java.lang.Class

But if I directly use the code in the handler it works.
Why am I losing the parameter type?

Answer (score 1):

You are not loosing the parameter type. You get it returned by `pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0]`.

But, instead of (what you for some reason expect) `Class` the returned type argument is a `TypeVariable`. Which is correct.

To get your `Class` check `getBounds()`.